# Downloading an extension-less file from a sub-folder in my project using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am trying to download an extension-less file stored in my project sub-folder with path "/static/assets/file-name" using javascript. The file contains simple text.

I have written the following function "downloadFile" to download the file, which downloads the file with extension ".txt" whenever the function is called.

```
downloadFile () {
      let element = document.createElement('a')
      element.setAttribute('href', '/static/assets/file-name')
      element.setAttribute('download', 'file-name')
      element.style.display = 'none'
      document.body.appendChild(element)
      element.click()
      document.body.removeChild(element)
    }
```

The file gets downloaded in .txt format (even though I have stored it without any extension in my project sub-folder), but I need it to be downloaded without an extension (similarly to the file that gets downloaded here https://www.amazon.com/apple-app-site-association. Can anybody suggest any corrections in my code or suggest an alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the http response headers of the file download? What is its mime type?

Comment: I don't know how to check what you asked for @Bergi, but this is the type of file I want to be downloaded  https://www.amazon.com/apple-app-site-association

Comment: Use the network panel of the [browser devtools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525)

Comment: @Bergi `accept-ranges: bytes
age: 278
cache-control: public,max-age=600
content-length: 29636
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Wed, 10 Jul 2019 10:08:45 GMT
etag: "e0fb6388d92156f18f658f9132e88a67"
last-modified: Thu, 04 Jul 2019 13:09:06 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 304
via: 1.1 7dda57f7e6978046952c757eba986c68.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: Mqy5eIWbLB5sKY0qeIDONqDIblvlUGvdCsZbESanYjAf92dGnRB83w==
x-amz-cf-pop: HYD50-C1
x-amz-version-id: U6fgaY0VhDpY9VU9CzjZjmBhXTXpcEQY
x-cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront`

Comment: Hm, `content-type: application/octet-stream` looks fine.

Comment: @Bergi the above is the response header of the type of file I want to get downloaded (that is on https://www.amazon.com/apple-app-site-association) not the file I am currently downloading through my own code

Comment: this is the response header of the file I am currently downloading `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"725-Qzo9Rw19bfH2hYZBHHmbcEiXUU4"
Date: Wed, 10 Jul 2019 10:25:20 GMT
Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: looks like you might need to set a content-type header in your server. Otherwise the browser will likely assume it's text

Comment: @KeithM That's a response without the actual data, saying just that it's still the same as the cached one. Empty your cache and try again. (You can also disable caching in the devtools)